# Standard way to filter nude/explicit user generated content on iOS

Tags: ios, image, image-processing

This is a situation where it is impractical to preapprove images by a moderator.

I've thought of two solutions:

-Have a flag/report button and automatically remove image if it is reported a certain number of times per time it's viewed.

-Use library that detects nudity in images.

The problem with the first way is that a) I would have to come up with a threshold number that isn't too sensitive or isn't sensitive enough and b) this reporting method will necessarily have people seeing the images before they report them.

The problem with the second way is that from what I've read, image detection for nudity is generally unreliable.

So I guess I'm wondering what the normal way to do this must be.  There are so many apps on the app store with user generated content that there must be a good way to do this.  My main fear/question is that will Apple ban an app that has any porn, even if the developer took the bit of appropriate action that he could take to prevent this from happening.  If I used a combination of these two approaches, I feel like it would be acceptable for the sake of my app, but will Apple ban any app that leaks a little porn?  Are there any better approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Can't give you too detailed of an answer here as I don't have a lot of experience with CoreML , but you could try using CoreML along with a Machine Learning model for nudity (which you should be able to find for free), and filter every image/video that your user uploads with the model.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that